# Prove that $abc(a^2+b^2+c^2-2abc-2a-2b-2c)+ab(a+b-2)+bc(b+c-2)+ca(c+a-2)+a+b+c \le 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, real-numbers, substitution, symmetric-polynomials

Prove that if the real numbers $a,b,c$ lie in the interval $[0,1]$,
then: 
\begin{align*}
abc(a^2+b^2+c^2-2abc-2a-2b-2c)+ab(a+b-2)+bc(b+c-2)+ca(c+a-2)+a+b+c \le 2.
\end{align*}

I've tried this:
\begin{align*}
abc(a^2+b^2+c^2-2abc-2a-2b-2c)+ab(a+b-2)+bc(b+c-2)+
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
+ ca(c+a-2)+(a+b+c-2) \le abc(a^2+b^2+c^2-2abc-2a-2b-2c)+
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
+ab(2-2)+bc(2-2)+ca(2-2)+(3-2)=
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
=abc(a^2+b^2+c^2-2abc-2a-2b-2c)+1
\end{align*}

but that $1$ in the last line ruins it even though that first term is clearly negative. Can anyone help me?

Comment: According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+abc(a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%2Bc%5E2-2abc-2a-2b-2c)%2Bab(a%2Bb-2)%2Bbc(b%2Bc-2)%2Bca(c%2Ba-2)%2Ba%2Bb%2Bc+for+0%3C%3Da%3C%3D1,+0%3C%3Db%3C%3D1,0%3C%3Dc%3C%3D1) the maximum of $2$ is attained when one of the variables is $0$ and the other $2$ are $1$.  Maybe you can show that given any $0\leq a\leq b \leq c\leq 1$ the function value is increased if you replace $a$ by $0$.  Then you'd have only two variables to deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{cyc}ab(a+b-2)\leq0$$ and
$$abc\sum_{cyc}(a^2-a)\leq0.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$a+b+c-abc(a+b+c)\leq2.$$
Now, let $a=\frac{1}{1+x},$ $b=\frac{1}{1+y}$ and $c=\frac{1}{1+z},$ where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are non-negatives.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$2(1+xyz)^2+\sum_{cyc}(3x^2y^2z+x^2y^2+4x^2yz+x^2y+x^2z+xy+x)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.